# Will connecting a NEMA 14-50 to a IEC 60320-C13 in this manner present issues

Tags: power, ac, adapter

I have a japanese item in my house which takes a considerable amount of power (>1.5 kW) and takes a C13 power plug expecting 210-250V at 50-60Hz.

My idea was to connect a NEMA 14-50 power cord in such a way that it will provide the needed voltage to the target. Here was my connection idea:

[image]

My main concern is that when you conventionally think about the wall socket, the earth is the same as neutral (in terms of electric potential). With this setup, the earth will not be the same as either prong, which I fear could introduce safety hazards.

Are my worries justified, or will this configuration be benign?

Comment: That’s how I would do it. Highly unlikely that you need a true neutral in a class I device. What is the 1.5 kW load?

Comment: @winny it's actually 2.2 kw, and it's a turbomolecular vacuum pump

Comment: Does it require super low leakage current yet has terrible design for export (many countries do not have polarized plugs)?

Comment: @winny according to the manual, it has an average of 3.5mA to earth

Comment: Whoa! That’s no consumer device :-) If it’s expensive and/or your experiments in it are, I would consult the manufacturer. If it’s Applied Science or my own garage, I would plug it just as you describe.

Comment: @winny the manual also says that the connections can be N-L-E or R-S-E so I'm assuming it isn't polarized

Comment: Makes perfect sense (for export)!

Comment: IEC C13 plugs are commonly used on non-polarised 240V "schuko" cables  so I see not problenm with wiring them with two 120V lives.  if building this yourself start with a 240V cable  ( eg: UK AU or EU plugs)

Comment: Note that Japan does not use Euro style 230V, they use North American style 120/240V center-neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK.

It only uses 10A at 220V except on startup  maybe 50A, so I would make a cheater cord with an IEC type receptacle to plug in cord hard wired rather than Nema receptacle use just the 240V plug but wired as you have shown. L1&L2 may he swapped and Neutral is not required.  I presume you had a 240 V outlet for dryer or otherwise wire as you have shown from a dual breaker.

Comment: EV charger, but yes

Comment: I will report back with experimental results

Comment: Safe but 3.5 mA to wrist or knee will feel like a burn if bare feet on damp concrete.. nah that’s for floating chargers.. this is grounded no problem

Answer (score 2):

AC mains person here.

### Nope.  You have no overcurrent protection.

The wires are correct and if safety was no object, that'd be fine.

But no, you cannot put a 10A load on a 50A plug.  There's required to be a *reasonably* close match of loads to plugs so the breaker has a chance of tripping on overcurrent.

The correct plug for that cord is a NEMA 6-15, and you should be able to buy those off-the-shelf readily.

You will need to change the 50A breaker to a 15A and the NEMA 14-50 recep to a 6-15. Breakers must match receptacles. (NEC 210.21).

Further if your territory is using NEC 2020, the breaker will need to be GFCI.

If you need to support this load and also a 50A load interchangeably on this same socket, then you need to convert the receptacle to a subpanel feeding both kinds of receptacles with breakers to match.  If the cable is 6/3 AWG then as a feeder it can be breakered at 60A, which means you have a fair chance of successfully running both loads at once.

Comment: 10A is only the average current. Peak is much higher

Comment: @tuskiomi That's true for *lots and lots* of loads and the system is factored for that. What does the nameplate say?

Comment: I agree. NEMA 6-15. There is also a NEMA 6-20 that would be OK. My tablesaw uses NEMA 6-20 on a 20A GFCI breaker. The 240V GFCI breaker was expensive, and I had to order it (not in stock on the shelf).

Comment: @mkeith Yes, actually if OP wired it with a 20A breaker and NEMA 6-20 receps, a NEMA 6-15 plug fits.  That is due to an exception in NEC.

Comment: The load is considered industrial, and GFCI will not work in this case because of the average return current of 3.5mA to earth.

Comment: @tuskiomi If GFCI is required, you'll have to argue that with the inspector. They certainly do waivers for refrigerators and other devices known to cause nuisance tripping. Expect the inspector to closely examine the device's UL listing.  Also expect a requirement for some sort of safeguard so nothing else can be plugged into that receptacle. Hardwiring would be the safest bet.  Also if this is a kitchen, laundry or bathroom appliance, make sure the receptacle at least 6' from a sink or water source.

Comment: This seems like less of a problem for my cord wiring, and more of a problem for my receptacle.